# Adding Firebase Crashlytics either crash in runtime or fail unit test build

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to add Firebase Crashlytics to a new Android app (single module, no flavors). Since Crashlytics is missing from the IDE assistant plugin, I'm using setup steps from https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started:

- add gradle dependencies
- download google-services.json and put it in the /app root

Crashlytics is initialized for release builds only like this:

```
class MyApplication: Application() {

  fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Fabric.with(
        this,
        Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
            .build()
    )
  }
}
```

**The problem #1**: app crashes during initialization with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
```

Adding

```
<meta-data
  android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
  android:value="{blah-blah-key}" />
```

to AndroidManifest.xml fixes the issue (I'm seeing crashes in firebase console), but now I'm getting

**Problem #2**: running unit tests (`gradle test`) fails with

```
> Task :app:fabricGenerateResourcesRelease FAILED
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: blah-blah-key
```

TL;DR - gradle fails to run unit tests if Fabric api key is present in manifest, app crashes in runtime if it's not present. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong, but not sure what exactly :(

Comment: Did you resolve this?  I have the same error

Comment: Nope :( I think that introducing separate Application classes for debug and release build types (with crashlytics configuration only in release) should fix the issue, but I haven't tried that yet

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6288)
```

In my case it was because I forgot to add `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` in `/app/build.gradle`

I did everything exactly according to the [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android) and my application was able to send reports to Crashlytics. And I didn't add a `io.fabric.ApiKey`.

Comment: are you able to run `gradle test`?

Comment: @MykhailoGaidai, yes. BUILD SUCCESSFUL. Need to mark that I have `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` in my project for debug build. So I also added application `com.myapp.debug` in firebase console (in same project) and in `google-services.json` in `client` array. At first there was only `com.myapp`. I'm trying to set up getting errors in a debug build.

Comment: @AnatolySamoylenko adding `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` in `/app/build.gradle` worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Well in my case:

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta01'
```

was missing in project level `build.gradle` 
and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

was missing in the app-level `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

For problme 1, I fix my crash problem with add below code in `build.gradle`.

The `build.gradle` in project level:

```
buildscript {
...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.6.1'
        ...
    }
}
```

The `build.gradle` in app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' // Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
...
dependencies {
    // Declare the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
    ...
}
```